# Can't open serial connection in Pyserial: "termios.error: (22, 'Invalid argument') "

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm having problem executing the following code:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/tty.FireFly-16CB-SPP',
    baudrate=115200,
    #parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
)

ser.open()
ser.isOpen()
```

This worked yesterday, and I don't know what I changed. Now I get the following error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 32, in <module>
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 260, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 280, in open
    self._reconfigurePort()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 409, in _reconfigurePort
    termios.tcsetattr(self.fd, TERMIOS.TCSANOW, [iflag, oflag, cflag, lflag, ispeed, ospeed, cc])
termios.error: (22, 'Invalid argument')
```

I'm a complete beginner to Python, and can't decipher the error message above. I've tried reinstalling Pyserial, but that didn't fix the error. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, though I was using a 5 port USB hub with 3 different USBs all plugged into it, and it turned out the hub wasn't providing enough power. Once I got an externally powered USB (one that wasn't just pulling off the line from my computer's port) it worked just fine.

Comment: Same here. Errors on a hub, plugged directly into the back of the Mac problem went away. The port name changed too.

Comment: Similar problem with a USB hub, unplugging and replugging into the same hub helped.

Answer (score 0):

Is the port still there? I meen `/dev/tty.FireFly-16CB-SPP`. It could have a new name today...

Comment: Yes, from looking in /dev/ I see that the port is still there.

Comment: It may also be worth trying the old 'turn it off and on again' - i.e. unplug the USB and plug it back in. This solved it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.FireFly-16CB-SPP',115200)
print "port is open" if ser.isOpen() else "port is closed"
```

you dont have to call open() unless you changed the configuration of the port manually eg:

```
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 19200
ser.port = 0
ser.open()
```

and don't forget to cles the port when you are done with it

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled Python and downgraded to 2.6 which solved everything.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

Just run the miniterm.py from pySerial examples (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyserial/develop) .

It ran fine from shell: python miniterm -p ttyUSB0 -D
but when tried to load it into Eclipse. and run debug from there.
it gave me:

```
pydev debugger: starting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.0.0.2011040403/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 1134, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.0.0.2011040403/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 918, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) #execute the script
  File "/root/workspace/pyserial/src/examples/miniterm.py", line 120, in <module>
    console.setup()
  File "/root/workspace/pyserial/src/examples/miniterm.py", line 101, in setup
    self.old = termios.tcgetattr(self.fd)
termios.error: (22, 'Invalid argument')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on OSX, and the problem ended up being the baud rate was not supported.  Changed the baud rate to something more common and it worked!